# Call a sequence of variables with same name inside loop in python

Tags: python, loops, variables, sequence, variable-names

I have 5 empty lists `list1=[], list2=[], list3=[], list4=[], list5=[]` and list with 5 variable `var_list=[v1, v2, v3, v4, v5]`. I want to append each variable inside `var_list` inside a corresponding empty list. I do that work manually:

```
list1.append(var_list[0])
list2.append(var_list[1])
list3.append(var_list[2])
list4.append(var_list[3])
list5.append(var_list[4])
```

I want to do that in for loop, I known the elements of `var_list` can be called inside loop as `var_list[i]`, but how can I call `list` in such way, where all variables `list` with same name and different in numbers. `'list'+str(i)` cannot work. Can anyone please help me to do this work in one line inside loop.

Comment: You want a dictionary to store the lists

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a `dict` to hold all the lists. Maybe something like this:

```
my_lists = {
    'list_{}'.format(i+1): []
    for i in range(5)}

var_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i, elem in enumerate(var_list):
    my_lists['list_{}'.format(i+1)].append(elem)
```

After running this, `my_lists` will hold:

```
{'list_1': [1], 'list_2': [2], 'list_3': [3], 'list_4': [4], 'list_5': [5]}
```

---

Note: in this case it is asumend that the order of elements in `var_list` corresponds to the names of the lists (elem at position `i` in `var_list` will go to the list with `i` in its name).

Comment: Thank you very much. It is work, but is it the only way? I have huge data.

Comment: @hhtt If you want more specific help we need more specific information of what exactly you need. You could ask a new question with more specific information.